# How to trigger a list according to input text with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js for auto fill a form. But when i fill form i need to click input and press any key to trigger list which is related with card number.

Example:
[when page loaded all areas filling automated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbhIY.png)

when page loaded all data are filling by javascript. But installemens is no seeing till i click and press any button to card number area.

when i click card number area and press ANY key in keyboard, the result is :
[real press trigger list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6v2s.png)

So how can i trigger this list with JS, or how can i simulate click card number area then simulate organic press with js, or anything else for solution.
Any advice will be accepted :)

Edit: ofcourse tried;

```
document.getElementById('elementID').click();
```

or [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

these solutions not working on my problem :(

Comment: can you share your code with short explanation what you exactly want ? your question in difficult to understand

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

to simulate a key press you can do a simple:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 78; // n code value
e.altKey = true; // Alt key pressed
$("#inputBox").trigger(e);
```